# Published azure function not showing

Tags: azure, function

I've published an azure function from Visual Studio and it seems to be have been published succesfully. I can see the dll file in the bin folder:

[bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3XJd.png)

But when I go to the function app, it's not showing:

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rP6B.png)

I've no idea why it is not showing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked on portal or this site https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/.

Comment: I went to the site and all the dll files are there

Comment: try to run in the console dotnet + your dll name